# Yolov5 is not detecting the labels

Tags: yolov5

I am training my model to detect the vertebra but after training, it shows no result. Is there any way I can get the results by tuning any of the parameters?

Comment: Can you give more details? ...maybe, of what you have tried so far?

Comment: Thankyou so much for the comment Chance. I augmented the data and it gave results :)